# Custom tabs or already iOS provided tabs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I saw in an app some tabs that i liked :

### [image: print screen]

Are the "recommended" and "most popular" tabs/buttons provided by iOS or ar they manually made and added to the app ? Do you recognize the design as being part of iOS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tabs are probably custom. The only built-in tabs provided in iOS are from [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), like you see at the bottom of the screen:

[image]